# How to convert a generic function with lifetimes into a function pointer

Tags: rust

This is of course a simplified version of my actual problem.

```
fn my_func<'a, 'b>(a: &'a i32, b: &'b i32) -> i32 {
    a + b
}

fn my_func_generic<'a, 'b, T>(a: &'a T, b: &'b T) -> T
where
    &'a T: std::ops::Add<&'b T, Output = T>,
{
    a + b
}

fn apply_function(x: &i32, y: &i32, function: fn(&i32, &i32) -> i32) -> i32 {
    function(x, y)
}

fn main() {
    let x = 10;
    let y = 11;
    println!("{}", my_func(&x, &y));
    println!("{}", my_func_generic(&x, &y));

    println!("{}", apply_function(&x, &y, my_func));
    println!("{}", apply_function(&x, &y, my_func_generic));
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:23:43
   |
23 |     println!("{}", apply_function(&x, &y, my_func_generic));
   |                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
   |
   = note: expected fn pointer `for<'r, 's> fn(&'r i32, &'s i32) -> _`
              found fn pointer `fn(&i32, &i32) -> _`
```

The question I have is: How can I use `my_func_generic` as a function pointer to pass it into `apply_function`?

It can definitely be used as such a function, as `println!("{}", my_func_generic(&x, &y))` demonstrates.

Trying to write it in a pointer gives the same error:

```rust
let function_pointer: fn(&i32, &i32) -> i32 = my_func_generic;
```

Annotating generic types manually gives the same error:

```rust
let function_pointer: fn(&i32, &i32) -> i32 = my_func_generic::<'_, '_, i32>;
```

Sadly I don't understand the error message, and don't have enough knowledge about the inner type system of Rust generics to understand how I could solve this issue, or if it's simply not possible due to some mechanism yet unknown to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:** In your case, you can do it as follows:

```rust
fn apply_function<'a, 'b>(x: &'a i32, y: &'b i32, function: fn(&'a i32, &'b i32) -> i32) -> i32
```

But in general, this is impossible.

---

There are two kinds of lifetimes in Rust: [**late-bound** and **early-bound**](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/early-late-bound.html). The difference between the two boils to when we bind the generic lifetime to a concrete lifetime.

For **early-bound** lifetime, we bind them when you're referring to their function. For **late-bound** lifetimes, referring to their function gives you a function pointer (or item) generic over the lifetime - what we call HRTB (`for<'lifetime> fn(...)`), and we choose the actual lifetime only when you call them.

The important point is that any constraints on the lifetime turns it into an early bound lifetime. This is because it is generally impossible to express constrained lifetimes as HRTB (more details on the above linked rustc-dev-guide page), although to be honest I still don't fully understand the reason.

So in `my_func_generic()`, `'a` and `'b` are early bound. However, `apply_function()` expects them to be late-bound (since the default desugaring for elided lifetimes in function pointers is HRTB, `fn(&i32, &i32) -> i32` is actually `for<'a, 'b> fn(&'a i32, &'b i32) -> i32`), and so this is a type mismatch.

In this case, you can just change `apply_function()` to bind the lifetimes as parameters, as I suggested above. This will still accept late-bound lifetimes, as we'll just bind them immediately. However, as far as I know, [in general it is impossible to convert an early-bound lifetime to a late-bound one](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/converting-an-early-bound-lifetime-in-fn-to-late-bound/56509).

Comment: Uff, that's a mouthful :D Thanks a lot for the detail given.

Comment: *"The important point is that any constraints on the lifetime turns it into an early bound lifetime.*" - is that why @hkBst's answer works?

Comment: I guess you could solve this more generally writing: `fn apply_function<'a, 'b, 'a2, 'b2>(x: &'a i32, y: &'b i32, function: fn(&'a2 i32, &'b2 i32) -> i32) -> i32 where 'a: 'a2, 'b: 'b2`?  [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=274732852c840854c724a3a4873341c0)

Comment: Isn't `'a : 'a2` redundant in almost all cases? Because you could just use `'a` in the first place?

Comment: @Finomnis: Probably in most cases you could even get away with just one lifetime everywhere and the compiler will just guess the proper one. But following the OP code, I was thinking what if `apply_function()` would call `function(x, y) + function(y, x)`, for example. Then you ChayimFiredman's solution would not work, but mine with `where 'a: 'a2 + 'b2, 'b: 'a2 + 'b2` would do.

Comment: @Finomnis Yes, this is what the other answer works. You don't constraint the lifetime, so they're late-bound.

Comment: @rodrigo You can just use only one lifetime in this case. I don't like to introduce redunant lifetimes, and in this case it even turns `apply_function()`'s lifetimes into early-bound as you're constraining them :) (not that it always matters, or even always bad (you cannot specify late-bound lifetimes explicitly so they're also less capable)).

Answer (score 1):

It works if you change your trait bounds slightly:

```rust
fn my_func_generic<'a, 'b, T>(a: &'a T, b: &'b T) -> T
where
    T: Copy + std::ops::Add<Output = T>,
{
    *a + *b
}
```

Comment: Why so? What do the trait bounds have to do with that?

Comment: @Finomnis, I don't know why this works.

Comment: Together with @ChayimFriedman's answer, I think I now understand the reason. *"The important point is that any constraints on the lifetime turns it into an early bound lifetime."*

Comment: @Finomnis, that may indeed be the explanation.