# mismatched types between method and lifetime-generic parameter

Tags: rust, types, lifetime

I expect the following Rust code to work

```
struct Expression<'a> {
    s: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Expression<'a> {
    fn foo(e: Expression<'a>, _: Expression<'a>) -> Expression<'a> {
        e
    }
}

fn accept(_: for<'a> fn(Expression<'a>, Expression<'a>) -> Expression<'a>) {
    
}

fn main() {
    accept(Expression::foo)
}
```

but I get an error message:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:16:12
   |
16 |     accept(Expression::foo)
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
   |
   = note: expected fn pointer `for<'a> fn(Expression<'a>, Expression<'a>) -> Expression<'a>`
              found fn pointer `fn(Expression<'_>, Expression<'_>) -> Expression<'_>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
```

The error can be fixed by introducing another lifetime `'b`

```
impl<'a> Expression<'a> {
    fn foo<'b>(e: Expression<'b>, _: Expression<'b>) -> Expression<'b> {
        e
    }
}
```

Can someone explain to me why this is necessary? Isn't `'a` already generic?

Answer (score 1):

Another instance of the [late-bound vs. early-bound](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/early-late-bound.html) lifetimes.

A similar problem is in [Using HRTBs to automate getter method unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73006849/using-hrtbs-to-automate-getter-method-unit-tests/). The problem is that while it `foo` is generic over `'a`, it is not *late-bound* but *early-bound*, meaning that it is fixed when we specify the name of the function and we cannot create a generic function pointer (`for<'a>`) from it.

Comment: That's very useful to know. If `foo` took and returned `self` instead of `e`, could this not be salvaged at all?

Comment: I guess you could just make `accept` generic over the lifetime of `self`, nevermind.

Comment: @isaactfa It could with a closure, like in the linked question.