# Creating a function lookup table

Tags: rust

I need a hash tables of keys to functions

The functions are member functions (`fn xxx(&mut self){....}`)

I have a test function

```rust
struct KeyLookup {
    keymap: HashMap<Input, fn(&mut TextArea<'_>) -> bool>,
}
    
impl KeyLookup {
    pub fn test() {
        let s = Self {
            keymap: HashMap::new(),
        };
        s.keymap.insert(
            Input {
                key: Key::Char('h'),
                ctrl: true,
                alt: false,
                shift: false,
            },
            TextArea::delete_char,
        );
        let f = s
            .keymap
            .get(&Input {
                key: Key::Char('h'),
                ctrl: true,
                alt: false,
                shift: false,
            })
            .unwrap();
        let mut ta = TextArea::default();
        f(&mut ta);
    }
}
```

it makes the map, looks up an entry and then invokes it.

But it doesn't compile

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
    --> src\key_dispatch.rs:28:13
     |
21   |         s.keymap.insert(
     |                  ------ arguments to this method are incorrect
...
28   |             TextArea::delete_char,
     |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
     |
     = note: expected fn pointer `for<'a, 'b> fn(&'a mut TextArea<'b>) -> _`
                   found fn item `for<'a> fn(&'a mut TextArea<'_>) -> _ {TextArea::<'_>::delete_char}`
help: the return type of this call is `for<'a> fn(&'a mut TextArea<'_>) -> bool {TextArea::<'_>::delete_char}` due to the type of the argument passed
    --> src\key_dispatch.rs:21:9
     |
21   | /         s.keymap.insert(
22   | |             Input {
23   | |                 key: Key::Char('h'),
24   | |                 ctrl: true,
...    |
28   | |             TextArea::delete_char,
     | |             --------------------- this argument influences the return type of `insert`
29   | |         );
     | |_________^
note: method defined here
    --> C:\Users\paulm\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib/rustlib/src/rust\library\std\src\collections\hash\map.rs:1104:12
     |
1104 |     pub fn insert(&mut self, k: K, v: V) -> Option<V> {
     |  

      ^^^^^^
```

I have seen code that does `TextArea::delete_char as fn(&mut TextArea<'_>) -> bool`

but I cant get that to compile either

Comment: Could you create a [MRE] that runs on the Rust [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org)?

Comment: I have had a [similar issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/116535) before. Try `|t| t.delete_char()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the same as described in [Using HRTBs to automate getter method unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73006849/using-hrtbs-to-automate-getter-method-unit-tests/).

The solution is the same: use an adapter function.

```rust
s.keymap.insert(
    Input {
        key: Key::Char('h'),
        ctrl: true,
        alt: false,
        shift: false,
    },
    |text_area| text_area.delete_char(),
);
```

Comment: Could you explain why, or point to an explanation

Comment: @pm100 I think I've linked an explanation, in my other answer.